# PaperTrail Usage - Versioning - Auditing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

I have a class 'Course' which has a sub class 'Subject'.
**A course has many subjects**.
I am looking to use paper_trail - 4.0.0.beta1 version to track any changes to the course/subject.

Course Class definition:

```
Class Course
has_many :subjects
has_paper_trail

end
```

Subject class definition:

```
  Class Subject
   belongs_to :course
   has_paper_trail
   end
```

I followed the following steps:

1. Created a course by name 'Maths' => This made an entry into versions
       table.
2. Created a subject by name 'Algebra' and assigned to
       course.
3. Created a subject by name 'Science' and assigned to
       course.

---

Now, when I look to restore the course object to step 1, As per paper trail, I am following these steps:

old_course = course.previous_version.reify(has_many: true)

But doing that is returning me with the latest course object which has two subjects. I am expecting a course object with 0 subjects.
What am i doing wrong?

**What I am looking to accomplish** is even if a subject is added to a course, I want to treat as a change of course and there should be a version created for it and when I go to any previous version, I should be able to see all the subjects that course had at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paper_trail`'s `created_at` attribute to get the moment where the Course object was last altered, and you can select the Subjects which have a `created_at` attribute smaller than the paper_trail's object, thus assuring you get the number of Subjects that were created only before that paper_trail version(Example, if you get the paper_trail version of when the course was created, the two subjects `created_at` attribute would be larger than the version date, which means it would return 0 Subjects).